# "No debugger set up" in Qt 5.4

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I have installed Qt Creator (Qt 5.4). When I debug my Qt project it wouldn't and says 'No debugger set up'.

Now I already have VC-2010 on my computer and I obviously have debugger (I verified all works) but do I have to download another debugger for Qt Creator? How do I configure the debugger to work?

Comment: Visual Studio has an internal debugger that cannot be used from outside of it. You need to install a debugger. Really.

Comment: The linked question is honestly not very clear and involves VS2012. My question is a simple use case where I have VS2010 installed Qt Creator is working but debugger is not enabled.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you have VS2010 or any other version of it installed, because it doesn't come with a debugger that can be used outside of VS. The linked question indicates what *else*, **besides** VS you need to install to have a debugger under Qt Creator. Again, it doesn't matter that the linked question "refers" to VS2012.

Comment: @KubaOber The OP there has `C++ x86 Compiler` in bold which I wouldn't asked that way (intimidating)..and he/she is not exactly sure what he is asking.

Comment: It's the answer that counts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys, I got clues from the links and figured it out but I am going to post the answer for what I did to resolve the issue. It is a little more complicated in the linked posts.

I thought I was all set since I had VC2010 installed but not so. It turns out I also had to install Windows SDK and since I am using widows 7, that was "[Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138)"

This alone fixed it and didn't have to do anything else.

** **Good to know** **

Another thing I learned was even though I had VS2010-SP1 installed, apparently there is VC2010-compiler-SP1 as well. It was that when I was installing let me k now that I need to install SDK first.

After I installed SDK, there is 'Windows SDK Configure tool' menu option that appeared in my windows start menu but I didn't run it and restarted Qt Creator, and the debugger was already working so I didn't have to run the configure too.!

When I started Qt Creator it bring up this [dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPfq9.png) press Ok and all done.

Answer (score 3):

It should detect it automatically.

Try to:

- close QtCreator
- Backup and Delete (or just rename) `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\QtProject` folder.
- start QtCreator again
- it should detect CDB in `C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows 64-bit\cdb.exe` or something like this

Alternatively, you could add it manually, by clicking `Add` button.

Additionaly:

- check that you have MSVC2010 Qt package installed
- why do you use 5 years old Visual Studio 2010, when the latest version is 2013 and it has free "Pro" version (Community edition) and it's has much better compiler and GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Just download and install this one http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.4/5.4.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw491_opengl-5.4.0.exe and every thing is setup for you

Comment: Is this only debugger or complete Qt 5.4 installation? I did install full Qt 5.4 already.

Comment: this is a full version of Qt using Mingw other than VC-2010 compiler.You may had downloaded those without a compiler which resulting in your problem

Comment: but I am not using mingw and I don't intend to, I would like to make it work with VC2010 debugger that I already have.